# postrotate script is not receiving rotated file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, exim, logrotate

I'm trying to do some processing on an exim log, but my script is not receiving the rotated log file name as a parameter - rather, it's getting the original log file name (which no longer exists)

```
/var/log/exim/*log" {
  daily
  rotate 3650
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
  nosharedscripts
  postrotate
   echo $0 $1 $2 >> /tmp/out
   /path/to/script $1
  endscript
}
```

The results in /tmp/out:

```
  logrotate_script /var/log/exim/main.log
```

I'm running

```
logrotate --force -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Output seems to indicate that it's renaming, then running:

```
renaming /var/log/exim/main.log to /var/log/exim/main.log-20160105
running postrotate script
```

This is on an amazon linux instance.  I've tried it with both sharedscripts and nosharedscripts options with no difference.

How can I get the old renamed file name?

Answer (score 1):

If result log file is (logfilepath).(log)-(20160105) formated, Maybe you can try this:

```
postrotate
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
/path/to/script $1-$DATE
endscript
```

If you want (logfilepath)-(20160105).(log) format, youcan use:

```
postrotate
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
LOGF=${1%*.}
/path/to/script $LOGF-$DATE.log
endscript
```

with $1 return logfilepath

Comment: I can calculate the file name, but according to the logrotate man page, I shouldn't have to.  So either I'm doing something wrong, or the man page is wrong.

Comment: pre and post-rotate script appear to receive the rotated file name as $1, so you have to generate result filename as i mentioned before